# Como resolver bug de centralização vertical no Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

O código abaixo funciona perfeitamente no Chrome 46, Opera 32, Safari 9, porem no Firefox 41 não funciona, o elemento fica preso no topo ao invez de ficar centralizado.

Execute o código abaixo:

```css
.o-hero {
    background-color: #25385f;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30rem;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.o-hero__dialog {
    bottom: 0;
    display: table;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="o-hero">
  <div class="o-hero__dialog">
    <h1 class="o-hero__title">Socialite is a awesome theme</h1>
    <p class="o-hero__desc">Perfect web architecture for high-end applications.</p>
    <a href="#">Buy this theme</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ficou bem diferente, espero que as modificações não impliquem no restante do seu layout.

```css
.o-hero {
  background-color: #25385f;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
.o-hero__dialog {
  margin: auto;
  width: 30rem;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="o-hero">
  <div class="o-hero__dialog">
    <h1 class="o-hero__title">Socialite is a awesome theme</h1>
    <p class="o-hero__desc">Perfect web architecture for high-end applications.</p>
    <a href="#">Buy this theme</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou muito bem!

Comment: Que bom, se tiver interesse pode dar uma olhada depois no conteúdo a seguir com outras formas disponíveis: http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/, você pode também alterar o _table_ do _display_ da classe **.o-hero** por _flex_ e remover o  _display: table-cell;_ da **.o-hero__dialog** caso queira contruir um layout flexível com mais elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma sugestão para resolver o seu problema:

```css
.o-hero {
  background-color: #25385f;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.o-hero-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.o-hero__dialog {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section class="o-hero">

  <div class="o-hero-wrapper">
    <div class="o-hero__dialog">
      <h1 class="o-hero__title">Socialite is a awesome theme</h1>

      <p class="o-hero__desc">Perfect web architecture for high-end applications.</p>
      <a href="#">Buy this theme</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou muito bem!

Answer (score 1):

Você não deveria utilizar o display: table pelos seguintes motivos:

"A declaração display: table faz com que o elemento HTML seja renderizado como tabela."
[Fonte: [Majour](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/propriedade-css-display.php#table)].

"If it looks,works and sounds like a table, it must be a table? Wrong!"

Tradução: "Se isto parece, funciona e soa como uma tabela, isso deve ser uma tabela? Errado!" [Fonte: [Colintoh](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)].

"There are two essential arguments for not using tables:
Semantic markup and avoiding tag soup. (too many tags)"

Tradução: "Existem dois argumentos essenciais para não usar tabelas: Semântica e evitar muitas tags."

[Fonte: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687968/is-it-bad-use-display-table-to-organise-a-layout-into-2-columns)]

---

Essas são declarações que incluem tanto os atributos table de CSS quanto a tag `<table>` em si.
Caso a ideia não tenha ficado clara, sugiro que leia os textos.

Mas enfim, o que eu realmente quero dizer com tudo isso, é que existem maneiras melhores de se fazer isso, como por exemplo:

**Flex-box (Flexible Box Model):**

```css
.o-hero {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #25385f;
  display: flex;
  height: 30rem;
  justify-content: center;
}
.o-hero__dialog {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="o-hero">
  <div class="o-hero__dialog">
    <h1 class="o-hero__title">Socialite is a awesome theme</h1>
    <p class="o-hero__desc">Perfect web architecture for high-end applications.</p>
    <a href="#">Buy this theme</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Explicação:
O que fiz aqui, foi apenas remover os atributos desnecessários como *position*: *relative* e *absolute* e seus similares; *display* *table* foi substituido por *display* *block* no elemento filho e acrescentado *display* *flex* para o elemento pai. Também redistribui as propriedades de *color* e *text-align* para o filho, já que ele é quem possui os textos. Pode notar que o código fico bem mais limpo.

Caso opte por usar essa solução recomendo a utilização de *vendor-prefixes* (-webkit, -ms...). Compatibilidade das propriedades de **Flex-box** segundo o [Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).



Ou também você pode simplesmente usar,

**Alinhamento Horizontal com translateY**:

```css
.o-hero {
  background-color: #25385f;
  height: 30rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.o-hero__dialog {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="o-hero">
  <div class="o-hero__dialog">
    <h1 class="o-hero__title">Socialite is a awesome theme</h1>
    <p class="o-hero__desc">Perfect web architecture for high-end applications.</p>
    <a href="#">Buy this theme</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Explicação: Fiz basicamente as mesmas alterações que do exemplo acima, só dessa vez o *position* *absolute* do elemento filho foi substituído por *relative*, adicionando a ele também as propriedades *top* e *translateY* que são os responsáveis pela centralização vertical. Para finalizar um *overflow* *hidden* no elemento pai para ocultar as sobras.

---

Entenda, não estou dizendo que essas aqui são as maneiras corretas e nem que utilizar table é errado, apenas estou te apresentando soluções um pouco mais sensatas.

OBS.: no elemento filho recomendo que você use `max-width: 30em` no lugar de `width: 30em`, para o responsivo!

Comment: Utilizei com flex e funcionou muito bem, obrigado!